# Loading data from a CSV file using <loadUpdateData> Postgres

Tags: liquibase

I would appreciate some suggestions.  I am accomplishing a simple load of one table with five records from a CSV file.   When I load the table, I get the below the error:

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
```

This is by csv file

```
1,Nate Happy,natehappy1761@me.com,1761 Brookview Trail,(205) 555-1212
2,Brigette Happy,brigettehappy7507@me.com,7507 Meadowgate Lane,(704) 555-1212
3,Katie Happy,katiehappy7507@me.com,7507 Meadowgate Lane,(704) 555-1212
4,Lauren Happy,laurenhappy@me.com,7507 Meadowgate Lane,(704) 555-1212
5,Jackson Hope,jacksonhope@me.com,7507 Meadowgate Lane,(704) 555-1212
```

This is my changeset for loading the data

```
<changeSet id="6-loadData" author="liquibase" dbms="postgresql" >
<preConditions onErrorMessage="Failed Pre Conditions for table" onFail="HALT"> 
      <and>
      <tableExists schemaName="public" tableName="contact" />
      <sqlCheck expectedResult ="1">SELECT COUNT(*) contact</sqlCheck>
      </and>
</preConditions>
<comment>Adding Data...</comment>
   <loadUpdateData catalogName="pg_catalog"
        encoding="UTF-8"
        file="src/main/resources/data/contacts.csv"
        primaryKey="contact_id"
        quotchar="A String"
        schemaName="public"
        separator=","
        tableName="contact">
      <column name="contact_id" type="int" />
      <column name="contact_name" type="varchar(45)"/>
      <column name="email" type="varchar(45)" />
      <column name="address" type="varchar(45)" />
      <column name="telephone" type="varchar(45)" />
   </loadUpdateData>
```

This is my changeset for creating the table:

```
   <changeSet id="4 Create Table" author="liquibase" runAlways="true">
   <preConditions onErrorMessage="Failed Pre Conditions for table" onFail="MARK_RAN"> 
       <not><tableExists schemaName="public" tableName="contact"/> </not>
   </preConditions>
   <comment>Creating Table named: Contact...</comment>
   <createTable tableName="contact" schemaName="public">
      <column name="contact_id" type="int" >
      <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
      </column>
      <column name="contact_name" type="varchar(45)">
         <constraints nullable="false"/>
      </column>
      <column name="email" type="varchar(45)">
         <constraints nullable="false"/>
      </column>
      <column name="address" type="varchar(45)">
         <constraints nullable="false"/>
      </column>
      <column name="telephone" type="varchar(45)">
         <constraints nullable="false"/>
      </column>
   </createTable>
```

Here is the sequence I am using to the primary key (contact_id)

```
   <changeSet id="2-Create Sequence" author="liquibase" runAlways="true">
   <preConditions onErrorMessage="Failed Pre Conditions for sequence" onFail="MARK_RAN"> 
      <not><sequenceExists schemaName="public" sequenceName="contactid_seq" /></not>
    </preConditions>
   <comment>Creating Sequence...</comment>
   <createSequence sequenceName="contactid_seq"
                    incrementBy="1"
                    minValue="1"
                    maxValue="9223372036854775807"
                    startValue="1"
                    ordered="1"
                    schemaName="public"/>
```

This is how I am using the constraint:

```
   <changeSet id="5-Add Constraint" author="liquibase">
     <comment>Adding contactid_seq sequence to Contact table...</comment> 
     <addDefaultValue catalogName="pg_catalog"
        columnDataType="int"
        columnName="contact_id"
        tableName="contact"
        schemaName="public"
        defaultValueSequenceNext="contactid_seq" />
```

Thanks for taking the time to read my post.

Russ

Answer (score 10):

I discovered the CSV file was missing the HEADER column names.  The LoadUpdateData's column elements use specific Java types, such as String instead of VARCHAR(45) and NUMERIC instead of "int".  Once I corrected these two errors, I was successful.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to change a string of quotchar, if you set it like in manual,

> quotchar="A String"

then Liquibase will mark letter "A" as quotes.

You can exclude it from changeset and use default html quotes charset

Comment: Liquibase manual dosen't explain it clearly. There is a lot of tricks when you use liquibase